# Determine the price of a resource in an azure subscription using azure api

Tags: azure

I am able to list all resources in a subscription using this API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list

Now i would like to iterate through this list and get the unit/retail price from this API - https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices

However, I am not able to zero in on the retail price for a certain resource based on the response from listResources

for instance when list resources responds with the below

```
{
  "value": [    
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/[SubscriptionId]/resourceGroups/[ResourceGroupName]/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/[StorageAccountName]",
      "name": "[StorageAccountName]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "location": "eastus",
      "tags": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

There are only a few fields which we can relate to as inputs/filters to the retail pricing api which are location = 'eastus', sku.Name = 'Standard_LRS', serviceName = 'Storage', serviceFamily = 'Storage' serviceName & serviceFamily are inferred values. So using these values except skuname in the api call gives back a lot of results

`https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter= armRegionName eq 'eastus' and serviceName eq 'Storage' and serviceFamily eq 'Storage'`

On the other hand i tried to look up the same information on the azure pricing calculator by choosing storage > storage accounts and in the estimate section there is an option to Display SKU's & Display Resource IDs, which are displayed promptly after enabling these options

[image]

[image]

I suspect the resource Id is the meter Id as the documentation for azure retail pricing api response mentions

```
meterId     000a794b-bdb0-58be-a0cd-0c3a0f222923    Unique identifier of the resource
```

So now when I query using the meter Id using this query

```
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter= meterId eq '14854f12-8d37-4299-842a-b0f2df82a305'
```

I get a far narrower result set back

So question is, what are the parameters and their values needed to zero in on the retail price of a resource in a subscription and if not listResource what other/additional api are available to get the desired result

Comment: I'm also struggling with this. Did you found a solution?

Comment: @JoseTruyol As far as I have looked into it azure pricing is complicated, each resource is priced based on hardware tier chosen and also the features you use and also each resource may have sub resources like a function app could have storage component so there are several parameters at play and azure apis haven't exposed these billing "meters" for all resources anywhere so its currently not possible.